# Horizontal Recycle View Then Vertical Recycle View Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I want to fetch image from database with this cardview:

[image: A Cardview with a 3x3 array of numbers from 1 to 9]

But I really don't know what should I do with the Recycleview.xml and the java.

Most tutorials I've watched only fetch image with a vertical cardview, whereas I need a 3x3 grid. How can I do that?

Comment: You can use `GridLayoutManager`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In short answer :

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, numberOfColumns));
```